# Get form values and pass it to Bootstrap modal on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get my form data and pass it as JSON to my modal dialog, which also should open on Submit button!

Here is what I've done so far:

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="configuration-form">
--unimportant--
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Please copy this code to your HTML</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <code id="configurationObject"></code><br/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
(function(formId) {
    $("#" + formId).submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var errMsg = "Something went wrong with form submit, please try again";
        var json = convertFormToJSON(this); //here I got my json object with all my form data


        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: {conf: JSON.stringify(json)},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(data){
                $("#configurationObject").html(data);
            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
})("configuration-form");
```

After Submit button is clicked I do get my JSON object with form data (I can log it after

> var json = convertFormToJSON(this)

and my modal dialog window is opened, but I do miss my data aka.
element with id="configurationObject" is empty.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to see the output of

    $("#configurationObject").html(data);

before using it in success block. Once you capture the output before making the call, use it inside success block. Give it a try and see if this works or not.

Comment: Yep, I found similar solution by just doing $("#configurationObject").html(JSON.stringify(json)); before ajax call. I think I'll leave it this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation `$.html()` accepts `A string of HTML to set as the content of each matched element.` .

Here you are passing `json data` instead of string. So first, you have to convert json response to string.  `$("#configurationObject").html(JSON.stringify(data));`

or you can use

`$("#configurationObject").append(data);`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to append() the data to #configurationObject rather than using html()?